# jQuery find percentage array based on selected value

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a select box having number count like;

```
<select>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
</select>
```

If I select one option it will take as number of customer. Then I ant to calculate percentage out of 100 for each customer in jQuery and save in a jQuery array.

If I select 2 then create an array
 `var perc= ["50", "50"];`
If selected value is 3, array become
 `var perc = ["33", "33", "34"];`

How can I do that, I tried like

```
var arr1 = [];
for(var k=0;k<num_cust;k++){
    var perc_vl = parseFloat(100) / parseFloat(num_cust);
    arr1[] = perc_vl; 
}
```

But it will only divide equally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Math.ceil` and `Math.floor` to do this like following.

```js
$('select').change(function () {
    var total = this.value,
      avg = 100 / total,
      avg_r = Math.floor(avg),
      short_100 = 100 - avg_r * total,
      arr = [];

    for (var k = 0; k < total; k++) {
        if (k < total - short_100) {
            arr.push(avg_r)
        } else {
            arr.push(Math.ceil(avg))
        }
    }

    alert(arr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='6'>6</option>
    <option value='7'>7</option>
    <option value='8'>8</option>
    <option value='9'>9</option>
    <option value='10'>10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/eqb0cvjq/1/

```
var select = $('select');

select.on('change', function() {
  var i = 0,
      value = this.value,
      arr = [],
      result = Math.floor(100 / value);

  for (; i < value; i++) {
    arr.push(result);
  }

  if (arr[0] * value !== 100) {
    arr[arr.length-1] = arr[0] + 100 - (arr[0] * value);
  }

  console.log(arr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you would like is everything to be integers and where it would have been a float split like in the thirds case, the last entry should have the remainder?

If so, try this:

```
var arr1 = [];
var total = 100;
for(var k=0; k < num_cust - 1; k++) {
    var perc_vl = parseFloat(100) / parseFloat(num_cust);
    perc_vl = Math.floor(perc_vl);
    total -= perc_vl;
    arr1[] = perc_vl;
}
// Handle last customer
arr1[] = 100 - total;
```